# What determine the transaction size of Monero?

Tags: transaction-data

Only the public key size of ring signature or both the public key size and signature size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both, and more. TX public key, TX extra data (usually payment ID), output one-time public key(s), input ring signature(s) and key image(s), ring confidential transactions (RCT) range proofs and commitments.